# what is wrong with my contact form, once i click the submit button it keep saying Error occurd! Please try again

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $to = 'marivelcoresis@gmail.com';  // please change this email id

    $errors = array();
    // print_r($_POST);

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $errors['message'] = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    $errorOutput = '';

    if(!empty($errors)){                                                        

        $errorOutput .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
        $errorOutput .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';

        $errorOutput  .= '<ul>';

        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            $errorOutput .= '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
        }

        $errorOutput .= '</ul>';
        $errorOutput .= '</div>';

        echo $errorOutput;
        die();
    }



    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $email;
    $subject = 'Contact Form : Texas Lawers Responsive HTML5 Template';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


    //send the email
    $result = '';
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
        $result .= '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
        $result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
        $result .= 'Thank You! I will be in touch';
        $result .= '</div>';

        echo $result;
        die();
    }

    $result = '';  
    $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
    $result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
    $result .= 'Something bad happend during sending this message. Please try again later';           
    $result .= '</div>';

    echo $result;
    die();


?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I guess you wrote this code.  Ever heard of debugging?

Answer (score -1):

At first glance and with the info provided, my suggestion is to change

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

with

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

In addition to this it will be a good idea to filter all `$_POST` variables, since the checks are not sufficient to clear any malicious code hidden in the text.